# Why R.xml file resourse is not being created when implements google analytics?

Tags: android, xml, google-analytics, analytics, tracker

I'm implementin anaylitics in my Android App, I followed this link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/ . I've applied gradle dependencies and I've added the google config file appropriately, but when I type the next line:


`mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);` 


But android cannot resolve or find R.xml file. I read about it and it suppose that such file must be created automatically, but is not happening.. someone had the same issue?.

I've already refactored the code and didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, I created a new project since 0 in order to check what were the differences in google-service.json file, in fact, such file in new project is different. When you create the project and accept to enable google analytics, your configuration file is different to when you nabled the service in firebase console over an existing project.

In old version of my file, where I had the trouble, I found this:

```
"services": {
    "analytics_service": {
      "status": 1
    },
    "appinvite_service": {
      "status": 1,
      "other_platform_oauth_client": []
    },
    "ads_service": {
      "status": 1
    }
  }
```

and in  the new project, I found this:

```
"services": {
    "analytics_service": {
      "status": 2,
      "analytics_property": {
        "tracking_id": "UA-XXXXXXXX-X"
      }
    },
    "appinvite_service": {
      "status": 1,
      "other_platform_oauth_client": []
    },
    "ads_service": {
      "status": 1
    }
  }
```

So, I just added the missing line, to my current google-service.json file, corresponding to:

```
"analytics_property": {
    "tracking_id": "UA-XXXXXXXX-X"
  }
```

And I changed the analytics service status to 2, now the folder R.xml is available and all works perfect!